# Capitalize first letter in every word

Tags: c#, winforms, uppercase

how can i capitalize every 1st letter in every word
anyone?
i'm a newbie so this would be a great help.

> like this david paul to David Paul

Answer (score 5):

```
var titleCaseStr = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(input);
```

Comment: should I put this code on event or something?

Comment: @davz_11 I don't understand your comment. It takes one string and returns another one. Use wherever you want.

Comment: I'm going to use this in a textbox. So if I type it will automatically capitalize the first letter of a word

Answer (score 1):

```
    string s = "Capitalize first letter in every word";

    System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo =  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    System.Globalization.TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;

    s = textInfo.ToTitleCase(s.ToLower());
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved simply by following method

```
        string s = "my test string";
        char[] c = s.ToArray();
        bool CapitalNext = true;
        string o = null;

        foreach (char ch in c)
        {

            if (CapitalNext)
                o += ch.ToString().ToUpper();
            else
                o += ch.ToString();

            CapitalNext = false;

            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(ch))
            {
                CapitalNext = true;
            }
        }
        return o;
```